# Populate Modal Window from Datatables w/ Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, modal-dialog, datatables, populate

I've got a table pulling from my MySQL database. I want to click on view and a modal window pop up w/ notes from the database.

I've seen a couple solutions online, but can't get any to work with Codeigniter.

Controller with link to modal window:

```
public function tableload_location_notes()
{

    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('Datatables');
    $this->datatables->select('
        VENDORLOCATIONNOTES.ID,
        VENDORLOCATIONNOTES.ADDEDBY, 
        VENDORLOCATIONNOTES.DATEADDED,
        VENDORLOCATIONNOTES.NOTES
    ', FALSE);
    $this->datatables->from('VENDORLOCATIONNOTES');
    $this->datatables->where('VENDORLOCATIONNOTES.LOCATIONID', $this->uri->segment(4));
    $this->datatables->add_column('edit', '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewnoteModal" data-id="1">view</a>', 'ID');

    echo $this->datatables->generate();

}
```

View with the actual modal script:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="viewnoteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View Location Note</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

That will open up my modal, but I don't know how to show the notes that I'm pulling from the database.

Comment: do you want to use modal for more than one instance of same data?

Comment: @Kyslik Nope. Just want the user to click on the "view" link and be able to read the "notes" and that's it.

Comment: You need to populate modal div and thats it. Put modal for example on bottom of your view and populate it normally as other data.